# How do I sync my iPhone 3G to OS X 10.9?

Tags: iphone

Anyone have any idea how I can sync my iPhone 3G and my Mac OS 10.9?  Seems Mavericks only uses iCloud now, so can't seem to hard sync the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to sync it directly by using the usb. Is it giving you error messages? What is it saying.

Also, you may need to check your sync preferences on the phone settings its self. What version of iOS is installed or is it jail broken?

Comment: I am not getting any error message...it just does not sync.  I am using the USB connection as always...just since 10.9 it is not syncing.  The iOS is 4.2.1.

Comment: Actually, I should clarify...it is syncing the apps.  Just not the contacts and calendars.

Comment: That sounds like the problem may be coming from the phone settings for calendar and contacts. Is it a google calendar, or a contact list from google? I would check apple support page / forums for similar cases, because the problem recently occurred from installing mavericks as well as the iTunes updates on OS X. The knowledge base should be more up to speed with mavericks and recent user issues.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has disabled local sync of contacts and calendars in 10.9.  From http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12117:

"If you use OS X Mavericks v.10.9 or later, your contacts, calendars, and other info are updated on your computers and iOS devices via iCloud."

Since iCloud is the only way to sync that info, and since the iPhone 3G cannot use iCloud, there is no way to sync that info with a 3G and a Mac running Mavericks.

So your only options are to roll back to an earlier version of OSX, run your own Mavericks server (may not work with 3G), use a third-party internet based syncing service, or wait for a third-party non-internet (USB) based syncing service.  See, e.g., https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5460803?start=0&tstart=0 for various posts on how to do these things.

Hope this helps.

Ron

Answer (score 0):

You can use the local sync built into iTunes 11.21 or later for syncing your contacts and calendars locally to iPhone 3G and older versions.

Simply create a replica of your contact cards and calendars currently stored in iCloud. Open iTunes version 11 or later with your iPhone 3G connected using the USB cable. Under the "Info" tab will be all your contacts and calendars listed.

I only see such a method as temporary for now until I purchase another iPhone. Too much manual maintenance is required. I can understand Apple's reasons for abolishing local sync in Mavericks since it was based on old outdated propriety code, hardly suitable for the latest devices on market today. Yet, the update to Mavericks will not stop you syncing contacts and calendars locally through iTunes (see attached screenshots).

[image]